# concatenate items in N lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have string of items as - string item = "a,b,c+1,2,3,4+z,x";

I split this string with + and add to N number of lists as 
List keysList = item.Split('+').ToList()

From this lists I expect to create keys as

> a1z
>
> a1x
>
> a2z
>
> a2x
>
> a3z
>
> a3x   etc:-

I have tried below block of code . but something is not correct here

```
private string GetValue(List<string> keysList, int i, int keyCount, string mainKey)
{
    List<string> tempList = keysList[i].Split(',').ToList();
    foreach (string key in tempList)
    {
        mainKey += key;
        i++;
        if (i == keyCount)
        {
            return mainKey;

        }
        GetValue(keysList, i, keyCount, mainKey);
    }
    return mainKey;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it...

```
string item = "a,b,c+1,2,3,4+z,x";

var lists = item.Split('+').Select(i => i.Split(',')).ToList();    
IEnumerable<string> keys = null;

foreach (var list in lists) 
{
    keys = (keys == null) ? 
        list : 
        keys.SelectMany(k => list.Select(l => k + l));
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y5Xs7Y)

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper function as follows:

```
static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateKeys(string[][] parts)
{
    return EnumerateKeys(parts, string.Empty, 0);
}

static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateKeys(string[][] parts, string parent, int index)
{
    if (index == parts.Length - 1)
        for (int col = 0; col < parts[index].Length; col++)
            yield return parent + parts[index][col];
    else
        for (int col = 0; col < parts[index].Length; col++)
            foreach (string key in EnumerateKeys(parts, parent + parts[index][col], index + 1))
                yield return key;
}
```

Usage demo:

```
string[][] parts = {
                       new[] { "a", "b", "c" },
                       new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" },
                       new[] { "z", "x" }
                   };
foreach (string key in EnumerateKeys(parts))
    Console.WriteLine(key);
```

Online demo: http://rextester.com/HZR27388

Comment: Hello. This solution has worked perfectly for me. But I chose the solution by Fiddle as that is more easy to explain. Thank you very much for this answer.